# Some questions on calculation on $D = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] = \{a + b \sqrt{-5} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**Problem:** Let $D = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] = \{a + b \sqrt{-5} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Show that the number $7$ is irreducible in $D$ and $(7) = (7,4+ \sqrt{-5})(7,4- \sqrt{-5})$. Show that $(7,4+ \sqrt{-5})$ and $(7,4- \sqrt{-5})$ are not principal ideals.

Could you give me some suggestion to solve this problem? Thank all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints:*

- If $7=\alpha\beta$, then $49=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$. Can we have $N(\alpha)=N(\beta)=7$ ?
- $(7,4+ \sqrt{-5})(7,4- \sqrt{-5}) = (7 \cdot 7, 7(4+ \sqrt{-5}), 7(4- \sqrt{-5}), (4+ \sqrt{-5})(4- \sqrt{-5}))=\cdots$
- If $\alpha$ divides $7$ and $4+ \sqrt{-5}$, then $N(\alpha)$ divides both $N(7)=49$ and $N(4+ \sqrt{-5})=21$.

Comment: @MinhNguyễnHoàng, check your computations: it should be $21$ not $11$.

Comment: So we get $(7, 4 + \sqrt{-5}) (7, 4 - \sqrt{-5}) = (7) (7, 4 + \sqrt{-5}, 4 - \sqrt{-5}, 3)$. $7$ and $3$ are prime numbers, $4 + \sqrt{-5}$ and $4 - \sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible, but it doesn't equal to $(7)$.

Comment: @MinhNguyễnHoàng, if $7$ and $3$ are in an ideal, then so is $1=7-2\cdot 3$.